# ReactJS Update State Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following useState declared to hold the state data for my registration form. In there I have state variables for form fields and corresponding error messages for those form fields.

```
const [registerForm, setRegisterForm] = useState({
        email: '',
        emailError: '',
        fullName: '',
        fullNameError: '',
        password: '',
        passwordError: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        confirmPasswordError: '',
        country: '',
        countryError: '',
        state: '',
        stateError: '',
        suburb: '',
        suburbError: ''
    });
```

Below piece of code check for the validation issues in my register form (at the moment it has only email, full name & password validation). If there is a validation message, it will set the relevant state value.

```
// validate form inputs
    const formInputValidation = () => {
        
        let result      = true;

        // clear validation errors before setting any new validation messages
        clearValidationMessages();

        let emailResult     = Validation.validateEmailInput(registerForm.email);
        setValidationMessages('emailError', emailResult.message);
        result              = result && emailResult.isSuccess;

        let fullNameResult      = Validation.validateTextInput(Constants.AUTHENTICATION_FORMS.registerForm.fullName, registerForm.fullName);
        setValidationMessages('fullNameError', fullNameResult.message);
        result              = result && fullNameResult.isSuccess;

        let passwordResult      = Validation.validateTextInput("password", registerForm.password);
        setValidationMessages('passwordError', passwordResult.message);
        result              = result && passwordResult.isSuccess;

        return result;
    }
```

The following piece of code set the relevant error state variable based on the validation message (value) it received. As an example if the email is empty, it will set the validation message for emailError in the registerForm state.

```
    // set validation messages
    const setValidationMessages = (name, value) => {

        switch (name) {
            case 'emailError':
                setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, emailError: value });
                break;
            case 'fullNameError':
                setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, fullNameError: value });
                break;
            case 'passwordError':
                setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, passwordError: value });
                break;
            case 'confirmPasswordError':
                setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, confirmPasswordError: value });
                break;
            case 'countryError':
                setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, countryError: value });
                break;
            case 'stateError':
                setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, stateError: value });
                break;
            case 'suburbError':
                setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, suburbError: value });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

However when I click the register button without filling any of the fields, the error message is shown for the confirm password only. The email validation and full name validation is not shown.

What I expected was to see all the validation messages(email, full name & password).

My thinking is that, at the time of setting the validation message for password, the ...registerForm is completely empty, in the sense the other validation messages (email & full name) are not set yet. Hence seeing only the password validation message.

I can declare each state variable for each form field and relevant error message and resolved this issue. But would like to know if it possible to achieve the same with my above implementation.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Below is the answer as suggested by Phil in the comments.

```js
// set validation messages
    const setValidationMessages = (name, value) => {

        switch (name) {
            case 'emailError':
                setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, emailError: value }));
                break;
            case 'fullNameError':
                setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, fullNameError: value }));
                break;
            case 'passwordError':
                setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, passwordError: value }));
                break;
            case 'confirmPasswordError':
                setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, confirmPasswordError: value }));
                break;
            case 'countryError':
                setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, countryError: value }));
                break;
            case 'stateError':
                setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, stateError: value }));
                break;
            case 'suburbError':
                setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, suburbError: value }));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `clearValidationMessages()` do? I imagine this is a timing issue due to state setters' asynchronous nature

Comment: It clears all the validation messages set in the state. such like setRegisterForm({...registerForm, emailError: ''});
        setRegisterForm({...registerForm, fullNameError: ''});
        setRegisterForm({...registerForm, passwordError: ''});

Comment: You need to update your `formInputValidation` function. Right now you call all the update states one after the other... The problem is each one is using the previous state... So only your last update happens (which is why the password shows up because it's the last validation in your function)... I suppose the easiest way to do this is to have each update return a state and then you continue to update that same state, then actually call the setState with that new state.

Comment: @SharpDev: can you give an example on that please ?

Comment: The solution is to use the functional setter (as per the duplicate). Also, you can clear all your validation at once instead of separate calls... `setRegisterForm((prev) => ({ ...prev, emailError: '', fullNameError: '', passwordError: '' }))`

Comment: In other words update (and probably rename really) your `setValidationMessages` to not call a react state update, and rather to update a state and return it. Then at the end of returning the chain of state updates you can call your `setRegisterForm` state update. I'll write up an answer with this implementation if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Phil I have corrected my code like you mentioned and it worked. And now it's showing all the validation messages. Below is what I did (this is only for the email, but same for others within the "setValidationMessages" function. setRegisterForm((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, emailError: value }));